# javafx: attach ChoiceBox to a TableCell on a TableColumn during Edit

Tags: java, javafx

The code below are instance methods of an object.

```
private StringProperty buySell;

// getters
public String getBuySell(){
    return this.buySell.get();
}

// return Property Object
public StringProperty buySellProperty(){
    return this.buySell;
}

// setters
public void setBuySell(String buySell){
    this.buySell.set(buySell);
}
```

In my `Controller` class, I have created a `TableColumn` for `buySell` string property with the code below.

When I created a transaction, there will be a new row on the `tableView`. However, I want to be **able to edit the buySell tableCell**.

**Question:** How can I embed a `choicebox` with values `buy`, `sell` within the `setOnEdit` function such that when I double click on the cell, it will give me a choicebox ?

I have my `choicebox` code below but I have no idea how to combine these things together.

```
    ChoiceBox<BuySell> buySellBox = new ChoiceBox<>();
    buySellBox.getItems().addAll("Buy", "Sell");
```

**Update:** Problem is still unresolved. However, by following the answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21860019/javafx-create-combobox-tablecell), this is what I have got so far. After creating an object, a table row is created but when I click onto the table cell `Buy` to **edit**, nothing happens (I was expecting a drop down choice box to appear and let me re-select my choice).

My table is editable, since I am able to edit tableCell using `Volume` using the code above.

Added in the images below to show that I am able to edit the `Volume` tableCell , but not the `buySell` tableCell, whenever I click on it.

[image]

Comment: post the complete code of your controller class.

Comment: I think that   `XXX.setOnEditCommit() ` is unnecessary.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to post the entire controller class, but it is way too long way to be posted in here. By unnecessary, you mean i should get rid of it ?

Comment: yes. for me it works fine without it.

Comment: instead of adding the entire controller class, I tried to give as much as info as possible, please see updated code above. I showed how I declared the tableColumn for buySell and volume. I deleted the XXX.setOnEditCommit(), I am still Not able to edit the tableCell

Comment: show the FXML-part TablleView

Comment: it is possible that editable="false" for that column.

Comment: Ahhh. You are absolutely right. This is such a careless mistake. My bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a cell factory that creates a `ChoiceBox` in the cell when editing. see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27900344/how-to-make-a-table-column-with-integer-datatype-editable-without-changing-it-to).

**Example:**

```
    public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        TableColumn<Item, String> col1 = new TableColumn("Column1");
        col1.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().nameProperty());
        col1.setCellFactory(column -> new TableCel_Edit());
        TableColumn<Item, Number> col2 = new TableColumn("Column2");
        col2.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().valueProperty());
        TableView<Item> table = new TableView();
        table.setEditable(true);
        table.getItems().addAll(loadData());
        table.getColumns().addAll(col1, col2);
        AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();
        root.getChildren().add(table);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    private List<Item> loadData() {
        List<Item> list = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Item item = new Item("item" + i, i);
            list.add(item);

        }
        return list;
    }

    private class TableCel_Edit extends TableCell<Item, String> {

        ChoiceBox<String> buySellBox = new ChoiceBox<>();

        public TableCel_Edit() {
            buySellBox.getItems().addAll("Buy", "Sell");
            buySellBox.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {

                String value = buySellBox.getItems().get(newValue.intValue());
                processEdit(value);
            });

        }

        private void processEdit(String value) {
            commitEdit(value);
        }

        @Override
        public void cancelEdit() {
            super.cancelEdit();
            setText(getItem());
            setGraphic(null);
        }

        @Override
        public void commitEdit(String value) {
            super.commitEdit(value);
            // ((Item) this.getTableRow().getItem()).setName(value);
            setGraphic(null);
        }

        @Override
        public void startEdit() {
            super.startEdit();
            String value = getItem();
            if (value != null) {
                setGraphic(buySellBox);
                setText(null);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (item == null || empty) {
                setText(null);

            } else {
                setText(item);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

**Update:**
in your controller class add the following:

```
fxTransactionLogBuySell.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Transaction,String>("buySell"));
fxTransactionLogBuySell.setCellFactory(column -> new TableCel_Edit());
```

You should also add this class (change `Item` to `Transaction` ):

```
class TableCel_Edit extends TableCell<Item, String> {
....
}
```

Comment: I did exactly what you have done above except I changed the name of `TableCel_Edit` to `ChoiceBoxEdit` and I locate this under my `Controller` class. I managed to compile the code. But when I double click on the cell, nothing happened.

Comment: don't forgot to make your table editable. add this : `table.setEditable(true);`

Comment: it is editable, since i am able to edit other columns except for the Buy/Sell column , where i want to edit by using a ChoiceBox instead of typing in String