# How to declare array in javafx

Tags: arrays, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I tried the below code and am getting values of "names" inside the while loop for a combo box.But coming outside the loop am only getting last value from database.

```
@FXML
private void fillcombobox()
{
    try
    {
        String sql = "select * from location";
        pst = gc.getConnection().prepareStatement( sql );
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        while ( rs.next() )
        {
            String names = rs.getString( "Address" );
            combobox.getItems().add( names );
        }
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
        System.out.println( "" + e );
    }
}
```

The above code fetches all values from table location and get the all values present in column "Address". And using object names I am getting values in combo box now using this code:
 `combobox.getItems().add(names);`

Please help me the possible way to get values outside the while loop.

Comment: The combobox.getItems() contains the list of names which can be accessed outside the loop.

Comment: @UlukBiy actually i need to access object "names" outside loop when ever i tried to access names object outside it only gives me last value in the column "Address".

Comment: The "String names" is actually only an **one** object, i.e. it keeps the address name (not names) of the current processing record (of recordset). So at the end of the loop it will keep the address name of the last record. combobox.getItems() contains the list of name objects.

Comment: @UlukBiy when ever i try to access names outside loop for this code  columnmain2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("Itemc"));
            columnmain2.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(names)); i am only getting only last value in "ADDRESS NAME"  in above code

Comment: Use the "names" in the @user99370 's answer below. It contains all addresses.

Comment: @UlukBiy tnq u so much it works!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91562/discussion-between-seban-and-uluk-biy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The String is single object it can store one value only, so for every loop it change value. that is the reason your getting last value. any ?s post comment

```
@FXML
private void fillcombobox() {
List<String> names=new ArrayList<String>();
  try {
    String sql = "select * from location";
    pst = gc.getConnection().prepareStatement( sql );
    rs = pst.executeQuery();
    while ( rs.next() )
    {
        String name = rs.getString( "Address" );
        names.add(name );
        combobox.getItems().add( names );
    }
    for(String name:names){
       System.out.println(name);
    }
 }
  catch ( Exception e )
  {
    System.out.println( "" + e );
  }
}
```

Comment: System.out.println("hell2"+name);//am getting all values here
            columnmain2.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(name));//but not here
           
   } whenever i add to comboboxtablecell it shows only last value in record.

Comment: i have to c your code then only i can tell what is wrong why your not getting values

Comment: here is my whole code:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32962914/how-to-populate-all-values-in-database-to-combo-box-inside-my-table-view-in-java

Comment: i have solved problem .problem withe the way your adding data to setCellFactory.i ll post the code in above ?