# How to fill second combobox on the basis of the value of 1st combobox dynamically in javafx

Tags: javafx-2

i am using javafx and working on a application CRUD. i nedd data in a combobox and when i select any of the data from one combobox the related data should be display on another combobox. the data source is mysql.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a simple example you need to add data form mysql to combo box [see this ? code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32962914/how-to-populate-all-values-in-database-to-combo-box-inside-my-table-view-in-java/32998155?noredirect=1#comment53822068_32998155) post a comment if any ?s.

**Example**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Table extends Application {
    private Stage primaryStage;
    private AnchorPane pane;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        this.primaryStage.setTitle("AddressApp");

        VBox v = new VBox(10);
        ComboBox<String> c = new ComboBox<String>();
        ComboBox<String> c1 = new ComboBox<String>();
        ObservableList<String> sList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        sList.addAll("b", "c", "dd", "dcd", "dddf");
        c.setItems(sList);
        c1.setItems(sList);
        // c1.valueProperty().bind(c.valueProperty());
        c1.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
            c.setValue(newValue);
        }
    });
    v.getChildren().addAll(c, c1);
    Scene Scene = new Scene(v);
        primaryStage.setScene(Scene);

        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```